# 2nd post doc or job in industry?

Tags: postdocs

I am looking for a 2nd post doc position but i dont have any publications in my first post doc. Is that lack of publications really matters to get another post doc? or shall I stop applying and look for a position in industry? My field is materials chemistry.

Comment: How long has your 1st postdoc been? 1 year? 2 years? Any particular reason you don't have publication yet?

Comment: it's been 2 years. the first project I worked on didn't go well. the second one is much better but it is in middle.  also I couldn't get the things (part of the results) in right from our collaborators. the main thing is I couldn't expect this sudden termination.

Comment: Sad to say, I would not consider hiring somebody who has spent two years as a post-doc without publications.  My expectations for post-docs is to be submitting their work in my group to conferences within 6 months, and journal articles before the first year is out.  However, that is based on having fairly clear project goals and milestones set at the beginning (i.e. I know it can be done). Your mileage clearly varied, and I'm sorry.

Comment: How many papers did you publish during your phd thesis?

Comment: @Danny Ruijters I was the first student of my Ph D supervisor as he was joined as a young faculty at that time. I had 3 publications as first author with overall impact factor 13+.

Comment: @jon custer  Yes. setting fair goals at the begining of project and support my supervisor is must to get results on time. that might have been missed in my case. Here also I joined under a new faculty. I always felt that I working better than in my Ph D. If my supervisor helps I can write from the scrap whatever I have but that is also lacking in my case.

Comment: Having been involved in science experiments and research level engineering projects for some time, including at national labs, I find it crazy that post-docs are expected to publish so much in so little time (note I myself am going down this road). A few things must be happening for the "successful" post-docs 1) they have finished most of the work prior to entering, and just a small amount remains until publishing, 2) the same as 1), but they are taking over someone else's work, 3) they publish something which really isn't consequential, or amounts to *salami slicing.*

Comment: Of course, I realize that there are always exceptions, and a few people don't fit this description, but the vast majority of scientists are no Fermi, Feynman, or Erdős

Comment: @daaxix The question was not closed because community members believe it is not "relevant to academia." It was closed because community members believe the answer to "shall I stop applying and look for a position in industry" depends on too many *personal* factors to be answered by strangers on the Internet. (See the text of the close reason.)

Comment: However, the first question is one that belongs here, *Does lack of publications really matter to get another post doc?*

Answer (score 6):

When you have published some nice papers during your PhD thesis, it still might be possible to land a 2nd post-doc, even when you did not publish during your first post-doc. Try to emphasize your accomplished publications and enthusiasm in your letter and cv.

You should, however, consider that it very likely will be more difficult to find a second one, especially at a top institute. They have often enough candidates to choose from.

Academia is often a very competitive place, and can be very unforgiving for setbacks, especially when not being tenured yet. This is really a pity, because there can be plenty of valid reasons why talented hardworking people hit a dry spell regarding publishing. (Think of not getting along with co-workers or supervisors, picking a niche that in retrospect does not connect well to one's specialty, going through a rough time in your life, illness, ...).

For some (many?) 'publish or perish' feels like 'perish while trying to publish'. I think that science does not always benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions.

1. Set yourself a time limit -- *I will continue applying for postdocs until (month, year), and if nothing has turned up by then, it will be time to go to Plan B (industry).*
2. Consider that the job search isn't just for employers/advisors to evaluate you, it is also for you to evaluate them.  Look at the person's track record -- both his or her own personal publication list, as well as his/her *students'* publication lists.  You need publications.  At this point, it would be a negative use of your time to do another publicationless postdoc.
3. Find *something* positive to report about what you accomplished in your first postdoc, to include in your CV or cover letter.
4. Prepare a very good job talk (I suppose this would need to be about something from your thesis.)
5. Since English is the international language of science, I would encourage you to set improving your English as a medium and long-term goal. Of course, the quality of English teaching varies considerably, so one has to choose the course carefully.